# Choosing between 2 Fibonacci alternatives

Tags: interview-questions, comparative-review, complexity, typescript, fibonacci-sequence

- Task:
  Return the fibonacci value at a given index.
  e.g: input: `6`, return: `8`.

Algorithm 1:

```js
public static fibonacci(input: number): any {
    if (input <= 1) return input;
    return this.fibonacci(input - 1) + this.fibonacci(input - 2);
}
```

> Time complexity: \$O(n^2)\$,
>   Space complexity: \$O(1)\$

Algorithm 2:

```js
public static fibonacci2(input: number): any {
    if (input <= 1) return input;

    let a = 0;
    let b = 1;
    let n = 0;
    for (let i=2; i<=input; i++) {
        n = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

> Time complexity: \$O(n)\$,
>   Space complexity: \$O(1)\$

---

Am I right regarding the complexities?

Can you suggest any alternatives that achieve the same result, with different time/space complexity?

Comment: wow, I've been downvoted the second I've posted it.

Comment: I'd believe the reason you were downvoted is because this isn't really asking for a code review, but it would be more of an opinion based answer, as you've seen yourself while searching for answers. Though I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Time complexity of the Algorithm 1 is \$O(2^n)\$.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute fibonacci numbers with both time and space complexity `O(1)`.

```
(n) => ((Math.Pow(phi,n) - Math.Pow(1-phi, n)) / Math.Sqrt(5);
```

where `phi` is the golden ratio:

```
(1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2
```

But if you needed to iterate fibonacci numbers one after the other, I would use an "iterator", then every other number would also be generated in O(1) and it would be better then the double formula.